# Raster menu does not have any tools in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

In the QGIS raster menu only raster calculator is available, how do you get other tools, like wrap (reproject)? Please see the image below.

[image: QGIS missing menu]

Answer (score 9):

From Menu,

```
Plugins -> Manage Plugins -> Enable GdalTools
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem: Processing plugin has been disabled.
Solution:
From Menu,

Plugins -> Manage Plugins -> enable Processing plugin