# Using raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, windows-11

I have a Victus by Hp computer with Windows 11 operating system , I tried to install different versions of QGIS software but I 'm having a problem , in the main menu , I cannot use most of the raster functions ( as if they are not never been installed).

Does anyone know what this problem could depend on?

Attached I put an image of what the raster allows me to do.

[image]

Comment: These answers may help: 
1. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49377/raster-menu-does-not-have-any-tools-in-qgis
2. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276229/incomplete-raster-menu-in-qgis3

Comment: If the prior comment's links don't solve your problem, you might indicate if you used one of the windows installers or the OSGeo4W network installer, and what version you installed.  Reinstalls don't typically change the QGIS application data folders so you might delete them and try again.

Comment: what version of QGIS are you using? the georeferencer is now under layers (as can georef vector and raster data)..